# drawing a line between each two points in a list respectively

Tags: java, netbeans, paint

Hi
I work with netbeans.
I have written a code which has two classes `(1) Demo (2) mainFrame which extends javax.swing.JFrame`

at first, my `mainFrame` will be run and it will show a panel that you can put some points on it and then when you click a button ; the dimension of all points will be store in a list , then I will send this list to `Demo class` because I have to put the points in an order that you can draw a line between each two points respectively.
I have two problems here :

1. I have that `list <listOfPoints>` ,how can I send this list to `mainFrame` class for drawing lines without making a new object of the `mainFrame` class?
2. I should work with paint method?
   please help me by some code example in java (with netbeans)

   Totally :

   ```
   I have a lot of points' dimension in my list ,I want to traverse my list in the i.e., paint method and draw line between each pi and pi+1.how can I do this?
   ```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google: netbeans java drawline

first answer

search

```
Graphics gg = buffImg.createGraphics();
        gg.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        gg.drawLine(10,10,buffImg.getWidth()-buffImg.getWidth()/10,
```

http://wws2.uncc.edu/tpw/tpwJavaNtebeansTutorial/index.html

regarding your question about drawing a list of points

```
void drawList(Graphics gg, List points){
   MyPointClass prev p = null;
   for(MyPointClass p : points){
       if(prevp != null){
           gg.drawLine(prevp.x, prevp.y, p.x, p.y);
       }
       prev = p;
    }
}
```

And if you don't feel like passing object from one frame to the other male drawList static and then you can do MyClassContainingDrawLineMethod.drawList(gg, points);

Comment: I have a lot of points' dimension in my list ,I want to traverse my list in the i.e., paint method and draw line between each pi and pi+1.how can I do this? thanks

Comment: check edit (I actually reread your post after posting and edited it to add the loop,

Comment: thanks ,but what should I write instead of "gg" in my demo class when I call this method in it?

Comment: gg is the graphics component that allows you to do your draw. I suggest you go through the tutorial I linked in my answer if your not sure how to handle the draw.

Comment: I get the whole but for example I have a JFrame which has panel on it.so what should I do in this situation ? jframe is my container or jpanel?

Comment: in you panel don't you have a  public void paint (Graphics g) method you can overide? (sorry I have only been using Android recently so I can't remember clearly)

Comment: JPanel is where you want to draw. You need to extend the panel and override its paintComponent() method. When you override it, it will be something like paintComponent(Graphics gg) The "gg" in this case is the name of the variable where you are holding a reference to the graphics object, you can put whatever you want there.

Answer (score 1):

Does it even matter that you're using Netbeans?

Also, to answer:

I think with Swing you generally override the paintComponent(Graphics gg) method to describe how you want your panel/frame drawn. And call repaint() when you want your program to actually redraw itself.

You may want to read this tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/
Especially the "Performing custom painting" section.

Also, have a look through the appropriate Swing and AWT parts of the API.

You can draw lines using the drawLine() method of the graphics class. Or by using the Line class (Line2D.Double ,etc) to represent your lines and then going, graphicsObject.draw(line) , etc.

What you could do is add the points to a list, as you add then to the graphics panel (repainting whenever you add one), then when the button is pressed, you could have run the method to process your list in the button's actionListener. So something like: list = demo.processList(list). Where processList has a header like: public List processList(List toProcess).

Comment: agreed that its not even linked to using netbeans but still I posted a tutorial using netbeans to make it simpler ^^